# How to use Tomcat as SMTP server to send and receive mail using Javamail

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I never used Tomcat and Javamail before. My main experiences was SpringBoot services. But now I have got task to create service to send and received mail for application with standalone Tomcat server. I cant understand how to use Tomcat as a mail server. I cant find any lesson on this topic. All tutorials about Javamail use outer SMTP servers like gmail or other.
Please help me where can I find appropriate tutorial or give me advice how to start teach this problem.

Comment: You cannot. Javamail is not meant to write your own mail-server, but to communicate with an existing one. Are you sure you have understood the task properly? Shouldn't you just write a front-end for an existing SMTP/IMAP server - i.e. a web application allowing to send and read e-mails, but the e-mails are going to be stored elsewhere?

Comment: I will check twice, but I write back-end. What do you mean "You cannot"? As I understand SMTP server can be part of Tomcat or can be installed over Tomcat or somehow like this.

Comment: Well, technically yes, you can build an SMTP server on top of Tomcat. But **why**? An SMTP server is damn complicated thing, if you want to implement it properly. Why you want to re-invent the wheel instead of just installing Sendmail/Postfix/Qmail (or Exchange on Windows)? And there are also tons of web UI solutions, so actually there is no need to implement these on your own, too. Just use what exists and customize it to your specific needs.

Comment: Anyway, if you really want to have/write Java mail server, have a look at [Apache James](https://james.apache.org/).

Comment: Tomcat is not a mail server.  There are many other mail servers available, such as Apache James.  Operating a mail server on the public internet is a non-trivial task.